# Vagrant up : The following settings shouldn't exist: name

Tags: macos, shell, vagrant

I've been trying to add a new link to an other site. I've edited my `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml` And just add the lines about tor2 in the config file.

```
sites:
    - map: agencedevoyage.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/agencedevoyage/public
    - map: tor2.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/tor_2015/public
```

I then ran a vagrant up and this is the output :

```
Willys-Mac-Pro:Homestead Mael$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

shell provisioner:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: name
* The following settings shouldn't exist: name
* The following settings shouldn't exist: name
* The following settings shouldn't exist: name
* The following settings shouldn't exist: name
* The following settings shouldn't exist: name
```

I don't understand where this come from. Any help gladly take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit this issue today as well. The fix was upgrading Vagrant and Virtualbox. Both of mine were outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally manage to do it. No quick answer, no true answer it appear I've broke the box by updating version of thing from here to here.

I finally install the latest version of virtualbox and vagrant, fixed everything up little by little and after a few hour everything is back to normal and I can work properly again.